# Run a command in erlang with a parameter

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm trying to write a erlang module for ejabberd and can't quite work out the syntax.

What I'm trying to do is when a user sends a off-line message, run a script I've written.

```
on_offline(_From, To, _Packet) ->
        ?INFO_MSG("recieved offline packet to ~p", [To]),
        ?INFO_MSG("Got offline message", []),
        osReturn = os:cmd("/opt/ejabberd-2.1.10/newmods/handleoffline.py " ++ To),
        ?INFO_MSG("Send to handler and got return ~s", [osReturn]),
        none.
```

However when I run it, I get a few errors, if I have ++ To there I get the error

E(<0.423.0>:ejabberd_hooks:294) : {function_clause,

However even if I run it without the ++ I get another error telling me Bad Match.

All I'd like to do is run handleoffline.py with the first part of the user ID, anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: Please, post the full errors and the code without the ++.

Comment: One error is that osReturn is an atom, should be OsReturn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the little information you have provided and assuming that your functions is being called with the ejabberd **offline_message_hook**  I can at least find a problem.
In

```
osReturn = os:cmd("/opt/ejabberd-2.1.10/newmods/handleoffline.py " ++ To)
```

you are trying to use the  **++** to concatenate the list you provided with **To**. But the major problem is that **To** isn't a string (list), and that generates your error. Your function is in the form of

```
on_offline(From, To, Packet) -> ok
```

where
**To** = **From** = **#jid** (see [jlib](http://www.process-one.net/en/wiki/jlib/))

one way to correct that would be to use

```
on_offline(_From, To=#jid{user = User, server=Server}, _Packet) ->
  ...
  OsReturn = os:cmd("/opt/ejabberd-2.1.10/newmods/handleoffline.py " ++ User),
  ?INFO_MSG("Send to handler and got return ~s", [OsReturn]),
  none.
```

because the field **user** on **#jid** is a string.

Edit: another error is that you need to chang osReturn to OsReturn because the first is an atom and will raise an error on your code, like [selle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630269/selle) pointed out

---

Edit your question and add more information if you have more problems, or to make this one clearer.